# Best way to execute multiple jdbcTemplate queries?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, api, jdbc

I have an api that is pre-fetching some data to be used in a ui dropdown screen. This would require queries to separate tables like this:

```
select distinct colors from table1;
select distinct categories from table2;
select distinct weights from table3;
etc
```

in the dao layer, I am used a namedParameterJdbcTemplate to call each query sequentially and then store them in a DTO.

```
try{
  colorsList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(getColorsQuery, 
  mapSqlParameterSource, String.class);
  categoriesList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(getCategoriesQuery, 
  mapSqlParameterSource, String.class);
  weightsList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(getWeightsQuery, 
  mapSqlParameterSource, String.class);
  filters.setCategories(categoriesList);
...
return filters;
```

is there a faster and more efficient way to make these db calls? Should I make the calls asynchronously? What's the best way to make multiple calls in a single api using spring boot?

Comment: From the looks of it, there might be a faster way to execute these, but I doubt there's more efficient way to do it. How different is the `mapSqlParameterSource` in different calls to this function?